# CubeMX IDE error issues with correct code

Tags: eclipse, stm32, freertos, cubemx

I recently installed cubeMX to use freeRTOS on STM32 controller.

```
HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_12);
```

If I type out the above I get an error.
If I have Eclipse auto complete the code I get the same error.
If I type out the code in visual studio and copy it into Eclipse everything works ok.

Error:

```
../Core/Src/main.c:296:30: error: 'GPIO_Pin_12' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'GPIO_PIN_12'?
```

296 |    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_12);  //Generated by cubeMX

[image]

Comment: After posting, I noticed that the auto generated code has Pin and not PIN at the end. The working version is all uppercase.

Comment: So just a typo, right? Are there reasons to keep the question and that you don't delete it?

Comment: Yes it's a typo, but it's an Eclipse(cubeMX) generated typo. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I don't know CubeIDE. You might ask here https://community.st.com/s/topic/0TO0X000000y2j7WAA/stm32cubeide